# model.compile is not a function

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, amazon-s3, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I've been trying to create a simple neural network to classify images between nsfw and sfw and I want to train it using dataset from aws s3. I want to run this tfjs-node script on lambda so that I can train this model whenever I have new data. The dataset will be taken from aws s3 to be used in the model. The model is a pretrained `mobilenet` model. I want to train it more and save it in aws s3 and then later use my newly trained model for more training and keep using the newest model for further training.

However I'm getting an error that `model.compile is not a function`. I'm not really sure where I went with the code.

The `dataset/images` has two folders, one for nsfw images and one for sfw images.

This is the code

```
import tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { promisify } from 'util';
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
import sharp from 'sharp';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import 'dotenv/config';

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

async function prepareDataset(datasetPath, imageDimensions) {
    const classNames = ['nsfw', 'sfw'];
    const xs = [];
    const ys = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
        const classPath = path.join(datasetPath, classNames[i]);
        const files = await readdir(classPath);

        for (const file of files) {
            const imagePath = path.join(classPath, file);

            const imageBuffer = await sharp(imagePath)
                .resize(imageDimensions, imageDimensions)
                .toBuffer();

            const image = tf.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer, 3);
            xs.push(image);
            ys.push(i); // Label (0 for 'nsfw', 1 for 'sfw')
        }
    }

    const xsTensor = tf.stack(xs);
    const ysTensor = tf.tensor1d(ys, 'int32');

    const xsNormalized = xsTensor.div(255.0);

    const splitRatio = 0.8; // 80% for training, 20% for testing
    const numExamples = xsNormalized.shape[0];
    const numTrainExamples = Math.floor(numExamples * splitRatio);

    const [xTrain, xTest] = tf.split(xsNormalized, [numTrainExamples, numExamples - numTrainExamples]);
    const [yTrain, yTest] = tf.split(ysTensor, [numTrainExamples, numExamples - numTrainExamples]);

    return { xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest };
}

// Load your dataset from S3 to a local directory
const sourceBucket = 'my-bucket';
const datasetPath = './images/';
const imageDimensions = 224;

const params = { Bucket: sourceBucket, Prefix: 'dataset/' };
s3.listObjectsV2(params, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error listing objects in S3:', err);
    } else {
        for (const object of data.Contents) {
            const objectKey = object.Key;
            const sanitizedObjectKey = objectKey.replace('dataset', '');
            const localPath = path.join(datasetPath, sanitizedObjectKey);

            try {
                await fs.promises.access(localPath);
                console.log(`File already exists locally: ${localPath}`);
            }
            catch (error) {
                // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
                const localDirectory = path.dirname(localPath);
                console.log('local', localDirectory)
                await fs.promises.mkdir(localDirectory, { recursive: true });
                const getObjectParams = { Bucket: sourceBucket, Key: objectKey };

                await s3.getObject(getObjectParams).promise()
                    .then((data) => {
                        fs.writeFileSync(localPath, data.Body);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Error getting object from S3:', error);
                    });
            }
        }

        prepareDataset(datasetPath, imageDimensions).then(async (data) => {
            // Load MobileNet model
            const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
                'https://tfhub.dev/google/tfjs-model/imagenet/mobilenet_v3_small_075_224/classification/5/default/1',
                { fromTFHub: true });

                console.log('model', model)
            model.load().then((model) => {
                
                model.compile({
                    optimizer: 'adam',
                    loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
                    metrics: ['accuracy'],
                });

                model.fit(data.xTrain, data.yTrain, {
                    epochs: 10, 
                    validationData: [data.xTest, data.yTest],
                }).then((history) => {
                    model.save(tf.io.withSaveHandler(async (modelArtifacts) => {
                        const buffer = await tf.node.encodeModel(modelArtifacts);
                        const targetBucket = 'my-bucket';
                        const targetKey = 'trained_model/model.json';
                        const params = { Bucket: targetBucket, Key: targetKey, Body: buffer };
                        s3.upload(params).promise()
                            .then(() => {
                                console.log('Model saved to AWS S3:', targetBucket, targetKey);
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error('Error saving model to S3:', error);
                            });
                    }))
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possible that a GraphModel (from `tf.loadGraphModel`) doesn't have compile and fit methods? Maybe you need a LayerModel for those?

Comment: @jkr i took the model from this url, they showed to use the `tf.loadGraphModel`. can we still use loadLayerModel? https://tfhub.dev/google/tfjs-model/imagenet/mobilenet_v3_large_075_224/feature_vector/5/default/1

Comment: i doubt you can use loadLayerModel. i hope someone else can answer your question, but i have a suspicion that a GraphModel does not have a compile method.